# Ignoring variable in function for Chi square test

Tags: r, function, chi-squared

I am building a user-defined function in r. It looks like this (the data frame is just an example):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

df<-data.frame(type1=c("a","b","c","a","b","c",NA),
               type2=c("d","e","f","d","e","f","f"),
               type3=c("d","f","g","e","f","g","e"),
               type4=c("e","f","g","e","f","g","e"))

f<-function(x){
  y<-df%>%
    dplyr::filter_(lazyeval::interp(~!is.na(x),x=as.name(x)))%>%
    dplyr::group_by_(x)%>%
    dplyr::summarize("Sum2"=sum(type2=="d"),
                     "Sum3"=sum(type3=="d"),
                     "Sum4"=sum(type4=="d"))
  y<-dplyr::bind_rows(y,setNames(data.frame("Total",
                                            sum(y$Sum2),
                                            sum(y$Sum3),
                                            sum(y$Sum4),
                                            paste(
                                              round(chisq.test(y$Sum2,y$Sum3)$p.value,3),
                                              "(Chi-sq.)")), 
                                 c(x, "Sum2","Sum3","Sum4","pvalue")))
  return(y)
}

result_f<-f("type1")
```

The problem is that I would like to include in the Chi-square not only two but the three variables (`Sum2`, `Sum3` and `Sum4`) because in this case only `Sum2` and `Sum3` are relevant but in other cases the function might need to analyze three variables.

Is there any way to include `Sum 4`, i.e. `chisq.test(y$Sum2,y$Sum3,y$Sum4)` instead of `chisq.test(y$Sum2,y$Sum3)`, but with some kind of conditional selection excluding those variables summing zero (for instance)?

Comment: I think you can do a `gather` into a single column

Comment: @akrun, I do not understand your comment. What do you suggest?